# Customizing SQL query programmatically

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have a sql query, say of the following form:

```
 select a, b, c from table t where t.a = "hello" and t.b = "there" and t.c = "world" group by a,b,c
```

I would like to have a Boolean condition `(d == true)` to determine the computation above such that when say d is set to true, the above query get executed, and when d is false, the query gets reduced to the following and compiled:

```
 select a, b from table t where t.a = "hello" and t.b = "there" group by a,b.
```

A simple if clause could help if its just one field/column/condition needs to be excluded/included. But the query I have is an extensive one with case statements, joins etc. It becomes unwieldy if the adds/edits to the query are multiple and I specifically need to test the changes in the result sets and cardinality by switching out parts of the query - table, column and groupby/where clauses.

Any suggestions as to how this could be achieved using  `oracle 11g (sql/pl-sql/t-sql)`

?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the following should solve your issue:

```
select a, b, c 
from table t 
where 
t.a = "hello" and 
t.b = "there" and 
((d == true and t.c = "world") or d == false)
group by a,b,c
```

(I'm not familiar with oracle sql so my apologies if the boolean equals is not correct)